# Write characters to file and replace the previous one without opening and closing everytime

Tags: c, system-calls

I would like to write and replace a string in a file whenever I have a new one.
For example

```
  #  | String in file
  1  | 10
  2  | 23
  3  | 98
```

I want to only open and close the file only once.
I would like to write strings without appending to the end of the file.
This is the code just to test the write sys-call

```
int value = 0;
int filedesc = open("testfile.txt", O_WRONLY, S_IWRITE);
if (filedesc < 0) {
    printf("Failed\n");
    return -1;
}
write(filedesc, "1", 1);
char buffer[4];
sprintf(&buffer[0], "%d",value );
printf("%s", buffer);
write(filedesc, buffer, 1);
```

And the result of the program on testfile.txt is:

```
11
```

How do I keep the pointer of fileDesc to remain on 0 every time I write? Or if you have any other suggestion to do this please tell me.
Thank you.

Comment: You can set the file pointer in the opened file by using `lseek()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reposition the offset associated with the file descriptor with the `lseek` system call:

```
lseek(filedesc, 0L, SEEK_SET); // move the offset back to start of file
```

If you move it back and rewrite contents to the file, but be aware that

- Depending on the OS, file contents may not be available to other processes until you `close` the file descriptor, but you may try `close(dup(filedesc));`
- You may need to truncate the file contents with the `ftruncate` system call. Arguments are: `int ftruncate(int filedesc, off_t length);`
- opening the file with `open("testfile.txt", O_WRONLY, S_IWRITE);` will not create it, hence the third argument is not used. To create the file, use the `O_CREAT` flag and also make the file readable: `filedesc = open("testfile.txt", O_CREAT | O_WRONLY, S_IREAD | S_IWRITE);`
- a 4 character buffer may be too small for some `int` values.  You should use `snprintf` to avoid buffer overflow.  `snprintf` returns the number of characters produced in the buffer, use that as the third argument to `write`.